# Deploying a Google Cloud Function written in typescript

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-build

I have written a cloud function using typescript and @google-cloud/functions-framework. My current workflow is to `npm install`, `tsc` (typescript compile), then `functions-framework --source=build/src/ --target=index`. Then I can visit `http://localhost:8080/` to run my function.

Once I have mirrored my GitHub repo on GCP, how do I get my code to build and redeploy future commits?

Comment: Hi @abc, Was my answer helpful to you?

Comment: Idk I decided to just use firebase functions

Comment: You can use cloud build linked with your Github repository for continuous deployment. I have written an article about this :- https://sushantdhiman.com/blog/2022/continuous-deployment-of-google-cloud-functions-written-with-typescript

Answer (score 3):

To deploy the function from your source repository, use the below command:

```
gcloud functions deploy NAME \
  --source https://source.developers.google.com/projects/PROJECT_ID/repos/REPOSITORY_ID/moveable-aliases/master/paths/SOURCE \
  --runtime RUNTIME \
  TRIGGER... \
  [FLAGS...]
```

For more information on this, checkout the doc [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploying/repo).